# push checked box values into an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

I have a bunch of check boxes and the value of each one is a different price. I created an object that holds the function to push the values into an array if the box is checked. When I console log the empty array it displays as empty so i know that works. I just cant get it to console log with the pushed value in it.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="bac" value ="1">bacon - $1


var allIngredients = {

 ingredientArray: [],
 baconBox: function() {
  var bacon = document.getElementById('bac');
  if (bacon.checked === true) {
    this.ingredientArray.push(bacon.value);
  }
},
```

edit:

```
 console.log(allIngredients.ingredientArray);
```

that returns an empty array like this "[]". I cannot get it to return an array with the value of bacon in it like this "[1]" when i check the box. The value of bacon is 1.

Comment: Are you calling the `baconBox` function anywhere?

Comment: `I just cant get it to console log with the pushed value in it` ... you'd need code that does `console.log(something)` if you want to console.log something ... don't you think?

Comment: As @Cerbrus said, you have to actually call it somewhere, like in event listener of changed checkbox.

Comment: `I created an object that holds the function to push the values into an array if the box is checked` - you've SHOWN something that pushes `bacon.value` to an array ... single value, single checkbox

Comment: How do you know that it works when you say it's empty? I don't get exactly your question here.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you should call the function `allIngredients.baconBox()`.

One option is to add an event listener, like so:

```
document.getElementById('bac').addEventListener('change', function() {
  allIngredients.baconBox();
});
```

Although a downside of this approach is that unchecking the box wouldn't remove the `bacon.value` from your `allIngredients` array.